# Google Maps API: SVG Marker moves relative to map when you zoom

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, svg

I have created two markers on a map, one a standard marker, the other using an SVG path.  The standard marker does not move relative to the map when I zoom out, but the SVG marker does.  Here is a fiddle where you can see what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/9A4ET/

Any thoughts on how to get the SVG marker to hold its place relative to the map?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SVG Marker Moves</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
    <style>
    html, body, #map_canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
<body>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<script>

var islandLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(48.692492,-122.908192);
var birdLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(48.692615936699596, -122.90869625529479);

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),{
  zoom: 19,
  center: islandLoc,
  disableDefaultUI: false,
  zoomControl: true,
  zoomControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
  },
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
});

var island_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: islandLoc,
  map: map
});

var bird_icon = {
        path: "m130.90909,164l54.09091,-23c0,0 -2.09091,-45 31.90909,-46c34,-1 37,6 42,23c5,17 -30,56 -30,71c0,15 23,21 56,40c33,19 56,62 64,81c8,19 14,39 21,46c7,7 16,16 15.09091,16c-0.90909,0 -14.09091,7 -15,7c-0.90909,0 -37.09091,-23 -46.09091,-23c-9,0 -35,-6 -57,-15c-22,-9 -35,-21 -35.90909,-21c-0.90909,0 0.90909,18 -0.09091,27c-1,9 -5,27 -5.90909,27c-0.90909,0 -7.09091,-15 -7.09091,-20c0,-5 5,-19 4.09091,-19c-0.90909,0 -3.09091,-16 -4,-16c-0.90909,0 -12.09091,0 -13,0c-0.90909,0 2.90909,10 0.90909,17c-2,7 2,31 1.09091,31c-0.90909,0 -17.09091,14 -18,14c-0.90909,0 8.90909,-20 8,-20c-0.90909,0 -1.09091,-15 -2.09091,-20c-1,-5 -5,-22 -5.90909,-22c-0.90909,0 -15.09091,-9 -29.09091,-50c-14,-41 37,-86 39,-93c2,-7 -8,-19 -8.90909,-19c-0.90909,0 -59.09091,7 -59.09091,7z",
        fillColor: '#000000',
         strokeColor: '#FFFFFF',
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        scale:.15
    }

var bird_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: birdLoc,
    map: map,
    icon: bird_icon
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must define the anchor for the symbol(for a symbol the default is the top left corner, while default for a image is the bottom center)

For this specific symbol the Point for a bottom center anchor would be approximately `258,381`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a3LKP/5/

---

Explanation of the calculation of the origin at bottom center(for inkscape).

Let's assume you didn't create the path(symbol) on your own, create a SVG-document with the given path:

```
<svg
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.0">
  <g>
    <path d="m130.90909,164l54.09091,-23c0,0 -2.09091,-45 31.90909,-46c34,-1 37,6 42,23c5,17 -30,56 -30,71c0,15 23,21 56,40c33,19 56,62 64,81c8,19 14,39 21,46c7,7 16,16 15.09091,16c-0.90909,0 -14.09091,7 -15,7c-0.90909,0 -37.09091,-23 -46.09091,-23c-9,0 -35,-6 -57,-15c-22,-9 -35,-21 -35.90909,-21c-0.90909,0 0.90909,18 -0.09091,27c-1,9 -5,27 -5.90909,27c-0.90909,0 -7.09091,-15 -7.09091,-20c0,-5 5,-19 4.09091,-19c-0.90909,0 -3.09091,-16 -4,-16c-0.90909,0 -12.09091,0 -13,0c-0.90909,0 2.90909,10 0.90909,17c-2,7 2,31 1.09091,31c-0.90909,0 -17.09091,14 -18,14c-0.90909,0 8.90909,-20 8,-20c-0.90909,0 -1.09091,-15 -2.09091,-20c-1,-5 -5,-22 -5.90909,-22c-0.90909,0 -15.09091,-9 -29.09091,-50c-14,-41 37,-86 39,-93c2,-7 -8,-19 -8.90909,-19c-0.90909,0 -59.09091,7 -59.09091,7z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Open this document with inkscape.

First go to `File->document-properties->page` to determine the document-height(for me it's **1052.36px** , I guess that's the default)

Then click on the symbol to select it, in the menubar you should see the properties of the object: **X** , **Y** , **W**(idth), (**H**)eight.

For me it's now:
**document-height:** 1052.36
**object-x:** 130.909
**object-y:** 671.362
**object-width:** 254.155
**object-height:** 286.093

**calculating the  y of the bottom :**
substract the object-y from the document-height(1052-671=**381**)

**calculating the x of the center :**
add the half of the objects width to the objects x(131+(254/2)=**258**)

So the anchor is `new google.maps.Point(258,381)`

Comment: anchor: new google.maps.Point(220,390) is at the feet of the bird: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9A4ET/12/) Is the top left corner default for a symbol documented somewhere?

Comment: [**By default, a symbol is anchored at (0, 0). The position is expressed in the same coordinate system as the symbol's path.**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#Symbol)  0,0 is top left I would assume(of the symbol's coordinate-system, not top left of the visible symbol)

Comment: My first calculation was wrong, I've used inkscape where 0,0 is left bottom and I needed to convert it to top left

Comment: Thank you, Dr. Molle.  I have marked the question as answered. Still not sure if I understand how I would determine the anchor point in future instances.  I take it I need to familiarize myself with Inkscape? Any tips on this would be appreciated.

Comment: @user1147171: I've added an explanation above